# Uploading new file to google drive in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I want to upload a file to Google drive in ReactJS based on a JSON response body from another HTTP request. Example of the JSON response:

I would like to have this in a file named '917897425.json' in a google drive folder. How can I achieve this?

I tried to use the 'react-google-picker' package in REACT (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-picker) but do not know how to use it.

Example of the JSON response:

```
[
{
    "917897425": [
    {
        "year": "2017",
        "name": "Blom Consulting AS",

    },
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "name": "Blom Consulting AS",
    }
    ]
}
```

]

I would like to have this in a file named '917897425.json' in a google drive folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Check here it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016733/how-to-make-http-request-to-upload-file-from-reactjs-to-google-drive